# When i run my android studio project it show following error

Tags: android, build.gradle

> Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbr, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

My app **build.gradle** code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.reayankarma.classattendance"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'



}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try to chnage the version of Support Libraries from 27.1.1 to 27.0.2

Comment: I changed all support libraries. After changing support libraries i got another error in build.gradle. Despite i run my project, it again throws same error.

Comment: I remember getting this error sometime back. I think I resolved it by updating all the dependencies to the latest ones.